# Create list of object attributes in python

Tags: python

I have a list of objects:

```
[Object_1, Object_2, Object_3]
```

Each object has an attribute: time:

```
Object_1.time = 20
Object_2.time = 30
Object_3.time = 40
```

I want to create a list of the time attributes:

```
[20, 30, 40]
```

What is the most efficient way to get this output?  It can't be to iterate over the object list, right?:

```
items = []
for item in objects:
    items.append(item.time)
```

Comment: 'efficient' is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: @Pyson: No it isn't, "efficient" is measured in complexity, computation time, lines of code and/or memory usage.

Comment: @Junuxx: most people do not test each and every instance of a comprehension vs a loop to see which is fewer CPU cycles. If you are using Python, it is probably about ease to write and read -- not absolute speed. What you stated there, computation time, lines of code and/or memory usage, may be completely at odds with each other. Double the code may be faster and use less memory, but takes more time to read and write as a programmer. Which is more *efficient*? Faster to execute or faster to write in Python? This is my point.

Comment: @Pyson: Right, that sounds much more reasonable. Still, there is always some objective measurement you could take to settle a discussion (if well-defined). Your initial comment sounded a bit like 'anything you do is fine' to me, but programming just isn't fine art.

Comment: @Pyson: Agreed—but I think by the "efficient to write" metric, the OP's code has to win, because he already knew how to write it, and got it correct… Maybe a better argument is amortized writing efficiency (as he learns to use comprehensions, he'll write future code faster, if not present code). Or, even better, _reading_ efficiency—when you look at old code/someone else's code, it's quicker to understand the comprehension and verify that it's correct than the 3-line loop version.

Comment: A list comprehension is faster in all cases, execution, reading, writing. There is no debate that it is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

List comprehension is what you're after:

```
list_of_objects = [Object_1, Object_2, Object_3]
[x.time for x in list_of_objects]
```

Comment: @Marcin: Actually, it's not guaranteed anywhere that list comprehensions are either equally, more, or less efficient than the equivalent list. Sure, you can figure out the answer by reading the CPython code (or the mailing list threads from when list comprehensions were proposed), but can you assume that would apply to, say, PyPy? So, a better thing to say is that there's no good reason to believe this will be more efficient.

Comment: What? Yes, there is. A list comprehension loop is done C-side, which is significantly faster than a Python loop. Any implementation will be faster as a list comprehension is a less expressive thing, and so can be optimised more efficiently.

Comment: @Lattyware: Really, a list comprehensive is done C-side even in Jython, IronPython, and PyPy? And you can guarantee that the dynamic JIT done by JVM, .NET, or PyPy can always better optimize a list comprehension than a loop?

Comment: As I explained, yes. A list comprehension is less expressive than a normal Python loop - a normal Python loop cannot make assumptions that a list comprehension can, meaning it is easy to make a list comprehension more efficient than a loop. In all implementations a list comprehension will be the preferred option. (Never mind the fact it is more readable, which should be the primary concern).

Comment: @abarnert even in PyPy and Jython, it isn't at all far fetched to say that using a provided high-level construct lets the implementation optimise it better than writing out the equivalent lower-level code yourself. It isn't done in C everywhere, but it *is* done in - to use the more general PyPy terminology - system-level code rather than app-level code.

Comment: @Lattyware: A JIT that works at the intermediate runtime level may not see anything that it can optimize on. In fact, the first implementation of list comprehensions in PyPy worked by translating the comprehension into the equivalent explicit loop (which means it's exactly the same speed, or actually slower if you're translating on the fly). And it's always possible that a JIT is smart enough to understand what appending in a loop does (or a tracing JIT gets the same effect without being smart). All things considered, a comprehension will _usually_ be faster, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, if you used a very early version of a Python interpreter or one designed explicitly to be inefficient on list comps, it could be the same speed, but that's a hell of a stretch. All of the mature projects people are likely to use will optimise list comps effectively. If they don't, they should be warning the user that they deviate from what the user expects. It is reasonable to assume a list comprehension will be faster. It's definitely not specific to CPython.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that it has _a chance_ of improving performance in a relevant way, and certainly worth testing (if you really need to squeeze extra speed out of a tight loop in Python, which almost never happens), but it's not guaranteed to be faster. As lvc says, it isn't all that far fetched to say that using a high-level construct lets the implementation optimize it better, but that's not the same as saying that it requires the implementation to optimize it better.

Comment: @abarnert `import this` "...Although practicality beats purity..."

Comment: @abarnert the extra bit of setup time involved in unrolling a listcomp into a loop is going to be constant in terms of the size of the list, and not usually be human noticeable. Given that, it is perfectly valid to say a listcomp is unlikely to be noticeably slower in even the worst case, and very likely to be faster in any non-naive implementation; and that combined with it being more readable, therefore a listcomp should be your preferred option - anything else is premature optimisation. "listcomps are faster" is a reasonable summary, even if it might arguably miss some minor nuance.

Comment: @abarnert (1) This has the same asymptotic behaviour as OPs code; (2) It is specified that (http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) "the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the for or if clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached [1]." The scope for performance differences is limited.

Comment: It's like arguing you shouldn't use `str.join()` because, potentially, someone could implement it as a series of string concatenations. While true, it's insane to suggest that it means you should not use `str.join()`. You can't spend your life second-guessing the implementation and assuming it has been implemented in the worst way humanly possible.

Comment: @Lattyware: Nobody is arguing that you shouldn't use list comprehensions. As I said in the comment on the answer, they're more readable, and easier to verify for correctness; as others said, they're also more compact, and faster to write. More simply, "beautiful is better than ugly". Those are all very good reasons to use list comprehensions. Hoping for performance micro-optimizations, however, is not a good reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
from operator import attrgetter
items = map(attrgetter('time'), objects)
```

Comment: Note that map returns a generator, not a list in 3.x, and that a list comprehension is far more readable (and probably faster) for something like this.

Comment: @Lattyware: +1. And if you actually _want_ a generator, you can use a generator expression just as easily as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
items=[item.time for item in objects]
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest (and easiest to understand) is with a list comprehension.

See the timing:

```
import timeit
import random
c=10000

class SomeObj:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.attr=i

def loopCR():
    l=[]
    for i in range(c):
        l.append(SomeObj(random.random()))

    return l 

def compCR():
    return [SomeObj(random.random()) for i in range(c)]   

def loopAc():
    lAttr=[]
    for e in l:
        lAttr.append(e.attr)

    return lAttr

def compAc():
    return [e.attr for e in l]             

t1=timeit.Timer(loopCR).timeit(10)
t2=timeit.Timer(compCR).timeit(10)
print "loop create:", t1,"secs"   
print "comprehension create:", t2,"secs"   
print 'Faster of those is', 100.0*abs(t1-t2) / max(t1,t2), '% faster'
print 

l=compCR()

t1=timeit.Timer(loopAc).timeit(10)
t2=timeit.Timer(compAc).timeit(10)
print "loop access:", t1,"secs"   
print "comprehension access:", t2,"secs"   
print 'Faster of those is', 100.0*abs(t1-t2) / max(t1,t2), '% faster'
```

Prints:

```
loop create: 0.103852987289 secs
comprehension create: 0.0848100185394 secs
Faster of those is 18.3364670069 % faster

loop access: 0.0206878185272 secs
comprehension access: 0.00913000106812 secs
Faster of those is 55.8677438315 % faster
```

So list comprehension is both faster to write and faster to execute.