# Get value array from object array

Tags: python, list

I have an array of objects

```
[<obj1>, <obj2>, <obj3>, <obj4>]
```

I want to get something like

```
[obj1.name, obj2.name, obj3.name, obj4.name]
```

I do not want to use loop for this, just looking for some more efficient way to get this

Comment: *"I do not want to use loop for this"* - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning @Tomerikoo's comment into an answer:

Use a list comprehension:

```
[o.name for o in l]
```

Note that this will not necessarily be more efficient than looping, but obviously more beautiful.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093436/6045800

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you:

```
l = [<obj1>, <obj2>, <obj3>, <obj4>]
list(map(lambda x:x.name, l))
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Yes, sorry. edited.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093483/6045800